# ¿Se puede convertir de algún lenguaje de programación a enamblador 8086 de emu8086?

Tags: c, ensamblador

Así de este estilo, lo que quiero es escribir el códico en algún lenguaje de programación y que me lo genere así

```
   ;leer caracter sin eco
   mov cx,10
   mov si,0
   leer:
   mov ah,07h
   int 21h

   ;leer 10 caracteres y guardarlos en cadena
   mov dl,al
   mov ah,02h
   int 21h
   mov nombre[si],al
   inc si
   loop leer

   mov ah,09h
   mov dx,offset[nombre]
   int 21h  

   ;leer dinero 
   ;primero limpiar pantalla
   mov ah,00h
   mov al,03h
   int 10h
```

Comment: Hola Christian, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, ¿Nos cuentas que has intentado para obtener el resultado que deseas?

Answer (score 1):

En linux tenes el `bcc`

`test.c`

```
int square(int num) {
    return num * num;
}
int main()
{
   return square(4);
}
```

generamos el asm (fast, ansi, salida asm, optimizado, 8086):

```
 $ bcc -Mf -ansi -S -O -0 test.c
```

da como resultado:

`test.s`

```
! 1 
! 1 # 1 "test.c"
! 1 int square(num)
! 2 # 1 "test.c"
! 1 int num;
export  _square
_square:
!BCC_EOS
! 2 # 1 "test.c"
! 1 {
! 2     return num * num;
push    bp
mov bp,sp
push    ax
! Debug: mul int num = [S+4-4] to int num = [S+4-4] (used reg = )
mov ax,-2[bp]
mov cx,-2[bp]
imul    cx
! Debug: cast int = const 0 to int = ax+0 (used reg = )
mov sp,bp
pop bp
ret
!BCC_EOS
! 3 }
! 4 int main()
! 5 {
export  _main
_main:
! 6    return square(4);
push    bp
mov bp,sp
! Debug: rootlist int = const 4 (used reg = )
mov ax,*4
! Debug: func () int = square+0 (used reg = )
call    _square
! Debug: cast int = const 0 to int = ax+0 (used reg = )
pop bp
ret
!BCC_EOS
! 7 }
! 8 
.data
.bss
! 0 errors detected
```

Limpiando los comentarios quedaría:

```
export  _square
_square:
push    bp
mov bp,sp
push    ax
mov ax,-2[bp]
mov cx,-2[bp]
imul    cx
mov sp,bp
pop bp
ret

export  _main
_main:
push    bp
mov bp,sp
mov ax,*4
call    _square
pop bp
ret
.data
.bss
```

ref: man bcc

https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-bcc/

Comment: El código generado en ensamblador si lo corre emu8086?

Comment: por lo que he visto de ese emulador (no lo he usado) tendrías que cambiar los `!` por `;` para indicar comentarios (o borrarlos), también parece que el emu8086 viene con algunos macros

Comment: ¿qué emulador usa usted?